# Error removing entity on AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datanucleus

I'm facing some problems trying to remove an entity from the database. I have an interface to abstract the AppEngine Entity from my business Object. I can easily Insert and Update, but when I try to delete I got the error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Non-owned relationships are 
>   not currently supported at 
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFKListStoreSpecialization.clearWit houtDelete(DatastoreFKListStoreSpecialization.java: 
>   123) 
>   at org.datanucleus.sco.backed.List.clear(List.java:817) 
>   at 
>   org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.CollectionMapping.preDelete(Collection Mapping.java: 
>   299) 
>   at 
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DependentDeleteRequest.execute(DependentDel eteRequest.java: 
>   71) 
>   ...

I got the interface ...

```
public interface ICompany extends IEntityBean { 
  // Getters 
  public List<IUser> getUsers(); 
  public List<IDepartment> getDepartments(); 
  public ICurrency getCurrency() throws Exception; 
}
```

... the implementation ...

```
public class GAECompany extends GAEEntityBean implements ICompany { 
  @Override 
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company") 
  public List<IUser> getUsers() { 
    return this.users; 
  } 

  @Override 
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company") 
  public List<IDepartment> getDepartments() { 
     return this.departments; 
  } 

  @Transient 
  public ICurrency getCurrency() throws Exception { 
  return this.currency; 
  } 
}
```

and the code to remove...

```
  // Get the entity manager 
  EntityManager em = this.getDBManager(); 

  IEntityBean persistent = em.find(obj.getClass(), obj.getId()); 
  em.remove(persistent); 
  em.flush();
```

I don't have any dependent objects I've just created an Company and now I'm trying to delete it. I assumed the mapping is right cause I'm able to INSERT an UPDATE the 
company. but not REMOVE! 
Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: Why use v1.0 of that Google JDO/JPA plugin when there is a v2.0 available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I just updated the version of Google JDO/JPA to 2.0 and it works well!